# Function that prints each element of a list and its index per line

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write a function that can print the element and index of a list. I want to do this without using the enumerate built in function and do it using for loops.

I was able to print out the element but I couldn't figure out a way to loop the index of my list.

Is there any good way I could work around this? Many thanks.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the `enumerate` function?  That's a rather artificial constraint;  it's *exactly* what `enumerate` is there for!

Comment: I just wanted to see if I could do things another way. I know I shouldn't reinvent the wheel but there are many possibilies that are out there for every solution.

Comment: Okay, fair enough.  In general for these sorts of questions it's helpful to know where the constraints are coming from (e.g., interview question, homework requirement, personal understanding, weird technical restrictions imposed by some other part of the codebase, etc.), since they don't usually apply to normal coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this, simply iterating over the `range` of numbers regarding the length of your `list`:

```
def item_and_index(my_list):
    for i in range(len(my_list)):
        print(my_list[i], i)
```

This is exactly what you need, a function using `for` loops and not the `enumerate` function.

Comment: This answer is very good, I do not know why this was downvoted.

Comment: @Yozuru Well, if you feel that it could be useful to users, you should upvote it yourself to indicate it as such.

Comment: It has been done, apologies since I am still fairly new. You and inspectors are sweethearts.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> L = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> for i in range(len(L)):
...     print(i, L[i])
... 
0 a
1 b
2 c
```

You could also try this:

```
i = 0
for elem in L:
    print(i, elem)
    i += 1
```

Comment: This answer is very good also, it was simple and easy to understand!